# Methods behaving like Class Fields

Tags: java, class, field

Sometimes you need values that are made up of more then just one value but the underlying values also can change.

**Example**

In a role playing game written in Java there could be a class that represents a player. He could have the fields "life" and "endurance". The last field could increase the life of the player. So we have "life" and the life increasing attribute "endurance" that results in the total or full life.

I would write something like that:

```
public class Player
{
    private int life;
    private int endurance;
    private int life_total()
    {
        return life + endurance;
    }

    public Player()
    {
        life = 10;
        endurance = 2;
    }

    public int get_life_total()
    {
        return life_total()
    }
}
```

I would write a method that looks like a field with brackets and behaves like a field. Is this an acceptable solution or are there better solutions for such situations?

In languages that have function references like javascript, would it be acceptable to use such function references for returning composed values?

Comment: Why don't you just use `public getLifeTotal() { return life + endurance; }`? That additional private method makes no sense.

Comment: For your example, this would be fine. But you don't need the extra private method. Just return the sum of the two fields.

Comment: Because when you write it in the way I showed it is more noticeable that this is a value of a player and you also can see faster that there is this kind of value for the player and not just a method like the others. Because normally you use getters only as return methods for real class fields, not for other stuff or for values that are no real class fields, i think.

Comment: @Tom you're missing a return type (as is OP)

Comment: `"Because normally you use getters only as return methods for real class fields, not for other stuff."` -- says who? properties are often calculated.

Comment: Ah okay, then i was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getter method should look more like this. There is no reason to have your getter method call another method to then fetch your variable.

```
public int get_life_total(){
    return life + endurance;
}
```